# Как сделать, чтобы MenuItem оставалось активным, пока не переключится?

Tags: wpf

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы меню оставалось активным, пока я не переключу на другой айтем? не могу найти свойство, есть ли оно? или как то по другому это делается?
При переключении меняются контролы.

```
 <StackPanel Background="FloralWhite" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <MenuItem BorderBrush="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Center"

                Header="Acheteur" x:Name="Achteur" Background="FloralWhite" Width="120" Click="Client_Click"/>
        <MenuItem  BorderBrush="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Center" Header="Vendeur" Background="FloralWhite" Click="Vendeur_Click" Width="120">
            </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem BorderBrush="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Center" Header="Agent" Background="FloralWhite" Click="Agent_Click" Width="120"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Что значит оставалось активным? Напишите подробно, чего вы хотите добиться в итоге.

Comment: хочу, чтобы менял цвет, оставался другого цвета например при нажатии, и пока не переключу на другой айтем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, для решения вашей задачи подойдет свойство `MenuItem.IsCheckable`, установка его значения в `true` позволяет переводить элемент из отмеченного в неотмеченное состояние и наоборот. Стоит заметить, что после того, как элемент становится отмеченным рядом с элементом меню появляется значок флажка и свойство `MenuItem.IsChecked` становится равным `true`. Зная этот момент, мы можем написать `Trigger`, который в зависимости от состояния `MenuItem.IsChecked` будет определенным образом визуализировать элемент меню.

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="Главное меню" IsCheckable="False">
        <MenuItem Header="Пункт 1" />
        <MenuItem Header="Пункт 2" />
        <MenuItem Header="Пункт 3" />
     </MenuItem>

     <Menu.Resources>
        // Создаем триггер на изменение свойства IsChecked
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                // Когда элемент становится отмеченным делаем его фон красным
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
                <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </Menu.Resources>
</Menu>
```

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделала, скоро экзамен , нужно по быстрому и это компромисс. Но мне кажется, это какая-то недоработка со стороны wpf. это же меню, и вполне логично, что оно должно оставаться включенным пока не переключат... надо будет поискать, как это действительно реализуется